# Why does one call $.makeArray() for passing array-like objects to $.map()?

Tags: jquery

The following is written in the jQuery docs for $.map:

> Array-like objects — those with a `.length` property *and* a value on the
>   `.length - 1` index — must be converted to actual arrays before being
>   passed to `$.map()`.

Is there a reason for this? If you try it with an array-like object, you can see that the result of $.map() does not change if you call $.makeArray():

```
var fruits = {"length": 3, 0: "Banana", 1: "Apricot", 2: "Peach"};
$.map(fruits, function(val, i) { return val; }); // Array [ "Banana", "Apricot", "Peach" ]
$.map($.makeArray(fruits), function(val, i) { return val; }); // Array [ "Banana", "Apricot", "Peach" ]
```

Comment: No, there is no reason to do this.

Comment: Always follow documented approach. Undocumented behaviors could change in different versions of library and break your code